# Maxmind geoipupdate gets http 403 on docker run

Tags: docker, geolocation, geoip, maxmind

I am using **maxmind GeoLite2** binary database for geolocation services and I want to **update** this periodically.

It works fine on updating through geoipupdate program installed via brew.
However Maxmind provides a [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/maxmindinc/geoipupdate) to update db periodically.
When I try to run docker command below,

```
 docker run --env-file IdeaProjects/ip-geolocation-service/src/main/resources/application.properties  -v /Users/me/GeoIp maxmindinc/geoipupdate
```

With the **environment file** refers to application.properties,

```
GEOIPUPDATE_ACCOUNT_ID=12345
GEOIPUPDATE_LICENSE_KEY=aaaaaaaaaa
GEOIPUPDATE_EDITION_IDS=GeoIP2-Country
```

I gets the following **error**:

```
# STATE: Creating configuration file at /etc/GeoIP.conf
# STATE: Running geoipupdate
error retrieving updates: error while getting database for GeoIP2-Country: unexpected HTTP status code: received HTTP status code: 403: Invalid product ID or subscription expired for GeoIP2-Country
```

Since my credentials is working on manual trigger, I wonder why it has not working on docker run? Any idea for spotting problem or anyone has faced with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write that you want to use the free GeoLite2 database but the ID you use looks like the commercial/paid one. Try the following instead:

```
GEOIPUPDATE_EDITION_IDS=GeoLite2-Country
```

Source: https://github.com/maxmind/geoipupdate/blob/main/doc/docker.md

Comment: ohh appreciate for the answer. It has worked. I also examined the document before but probably missed the difference between GeoIp2 and GeoLite2 on docker file. @cstol